# How do I sort through .csv columns with multiple strings (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to find the average rating for each genre in this [.csv list](https://www.kaggle.com/isaactaylorofficial/imdb-10000-most-voted-feature-films-041118) and I have run into a problem. The Genre column has multiple genres that are separated by commas (eg. The Dark Night has 3 genres Action, Crime, Drama). I have written code that would only work if there was one genre for each row and am unsure how to scan the columns with multiple genres.

```
data = pd.read_csv('movies.csv') # read in file
dataGenre = data
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Genre":dataYearScore['Genre'], "Score": dataYearScore['Score']})

genre_list5 = []
avg_scores5 = []

for genre in df5["Genre"].unique():
    genre_list5.append(genre)
    avg_scores5.append(df5.loc[df5["Genre"]==genre, "Score"].mean())

plt.bar(genre_list5, avg_scores5, width = 0.8)
plt.xlabel('Genre')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.xticks(rotation=65)
plt.title('Average Score for Each Genre')
plt.show()
```

If anyone could help out I would really appreciate it :)

[Here is a photo of what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vzxs.png)

Udate: Is it possible to make a new list with one of each genre? That should make it easier, I just need to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use split and explode.

```
df = df.assign(Genre=df['Genre'].str.split(',')).explode('Genre').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in df5.iterrows():
    genres = row['Genre']
    score = row['Score']
    for genre in genres.split(','):
        counter[genre].append(score)
```

Now you have the scores per genre